# Как добавить nonce к автогенерирующимся скриптам на Gatsby?

Tags: reactjs, csp, gatsbyjs

Пытаюсь настроить CSP на Gatsby с помощью плагина **gatsby-plugin-csp**. Поскольку при каждой сборке генерируются разные хэши *sha256*, их невозможно добавить в политику CSP. Для этого воспользовался плагином **gatsby-plugin-csp-nonce**.

Но все равно остаются ошибки в консоли [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Которые ведут на эти скрипты [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получается **gatsby-plugin-csp-nonce** не добавляет *nonce* к данным скриптам.
Как можно добавить этот атрибут вручную, если эти скрипты генерятся при сборке проекта?

Вот код настройки плагина

```
{
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-csp`,
        options: {
            disableOnDev: true,
            reportOnly: false,
            mergeScriptHashes: false,
            mergeStyleHashes: false,
            mergeDefaultDirectives: true,
            directives: {
                'default-src': "'self'",
                'connect-src': " 'self' https://mc.yandex.ru",
                'font-src': "'self' https://fonts.gstatic.com data:",
                'script-src': `'self' mc.yandex.ru https://www.google.com 'nonce-${nonce}' https://www.gstatic.com/recaptcha/`,
                'style-src': `'self' 'nonce-${nonce}' https://fonts.googleapis.com 'unsafe-hashes' 'sha256-47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=' 'sha256-MtxTLcyxVEJFNLEIqbVTaqR4WWr0+lYSZ78AzGmNsuA=' 'sha256-o4LYhp5wtluJ8/NWUV2vi+r5AxmP8X2zEvYHCpji+kI='`,
                'img-src': "'self' https://mc.yandex.ru data:",
                'frame-src': "'self' https://www.google.com",
            },
        },
    },
    {
        resolve: `gatsby-plugin-csp-nonce`,
        options: {
            disableOnDev: true,
            enableLogs: false,
            nonce,
        },
    },
}
```

Или может есть какие то идеи настройки CSP но без использования *"unsafe-..."*.